# Javascript checking telephone number - IF Statement

Tags: javascript, validation

My if statement isn't working 100%; I basically want it to be checking the length and if its digits, but if its left blank then the green text and style for errtelno1 - can you help me understand why? I'm new at this...its an 11 digit number

```
if (document.getElementById("telno").value.length != 11 ) {
    document.getElementById("errtelno").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errtelno").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("telno").style.border ='4px solid red';
    document.getElementById("errtelno").style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById("errtelno").style.fontWeight = "light";
    document.getElementById("errtelno").style.fontSize = "12px";
    isValid = false;
}   else
{       document.getElementById("telno").style.border ='2px solid green';
        document.getElementById("errtelno").style.color = "green";

}

if (document.getElementById("telno").value != /^\d+$/ ) {
    document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById("telno").style.border ='4px solid red';
     isValid = false;
}   else
{       document.getElementById("telno").style.border ='2px solid green';
}
return isValid; 
}
```

Comment: What kind of telephone number – formats vary hugely? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `document.getElementById("telno").value != /^\d+$/` Huh? You cannot compare string with regex. Use `RegExp#test`.

Comment: ah i see, i was using reg ex for email somewhere else, so is it like that - i missed a bit> that's what that line was trying to test - i wanted it to make sure there is just numbers

Comment: would it be like this: for testing whether a number
      var telno= document.getElementById('telni');
      var telnoRegEx= /^\d+$/;

     if (!telnoRegEx.test(telno.value)) {

Answer (score 0):

A little sample to shorten the problem. Only a sample...

```
var telno = document.getElementById("telno");
var errtelno = document.getElementById("errtelno");
var expr = /^\d+$/;
var isValid = (telno.value.length == 11 && expr.test(telno.value));

if(!isValid) {
  errtelno.style.display = "inline";
  errtelno.style.visibility = "visible";
  telno.style.border ='4px solid red';
  errtelno.style.color = "green";
  errtelno.style.fontWeight = "light";
  errtelno.style.fontSize = "12px";
}
else {
  telno.style.border ='2px solid green';
  errtelno.style.color = "green";
}
return isValid;
```

Comment: Ok thanks. so i need the document.getElementById for checking the (if!isValid)? (I've changed above)

Comment: If you save the value of `document.getElementById('x')` you can use this saved value again and again whereever you have `document.getElementById('x')`.

Comment: You should not edit the questioned code again and again. All comments and answers will become meaningless.

Comment: ok, which part of my code isn't executing? its making the box green but not adding any error messages - yes sorry i see your point,

Comment: It isnt assessing a blank field, i've worked it now. Thanks alot for your help Holger!

Answer (score 0):

The empty field can be left blank, this error is changed in the variable expr, where the expression for only a numerical format, as adds in length of varible to 11 in the curly brackets

```
// function to be called

function checkTel(){

// setting the variables

  var telno = document.getElementById("telno"); 
  var errtelno = document.getElementById("errtelno");
  var expr = /^\d+${11}/;
  var isValid = (telno.value.length == 11 && expr.test(telno.value));

// changes box to highlighted red and error messages appear

if(!isValid) {
  document.getElementById("errtelno").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("errtelno").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("telno").style.border ='1px solid green';
  document.getElementById("errtelno").style.color = "green";
  document.getElementById("errtelno").style.fontWeight = "light";
  document.getElementById("errtelno").style.fontSize = "12px";
  } 

  // if it is blank or correct input then box turns green

  else {
  document.getElementById("telno").style.border ='2px solid green';
  document.getElementById("errtelno").style.color = "green";
  }
return isValid;
}
```